# PHP while loop output to HTML

Tags: php, html

I have below DIV in html

```
<div class="result1" id="result1" name="result1"  >
    <table>
        <tr>
             <th> Date</th>
             <th> Bank</th>
             <th> Type</th>
             <th> Income Category</th>
             <th> Expense Category</th>
             <th> Expense Sub Category</th>
             <th> Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <?php echo $out; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

and I am trying to display below PHP loop output inside `result1`

```
while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()) {
    $out = "<tr>
        <td>".$row["date"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["select_bank"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["entry_type"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["income_cat"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["expense_cat"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["expense_cat_sub"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["amount"]."</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

The problem is I am getting only the last row of the loop inside HTML, not all of them.

I tried below method to echo the div id via php:

```
echo "<div class=\"output1\">$out</div>";
```

Problem with above method is output is showing at top of the page, not inside `output1` div. I would like show the result inside `output1` at the correct location.  How can I achieve it?

Comment: replace `$out = ` with `echo `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are continually overwriting the value of $out, so set it to blank to start off with and add to it (using `.=`) at each loop....

```
$out = "";
while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()){
    $out .= "<tr><td>".$row["date"]."</td><td>".$row["select_bank"]."</td><td>".$row["entry_type"]."</td><td>".$row["income_cat"]."</td><td>".$row["expense_cat"]."</td><td>".$row["expense_cat_sub"]."</td><td>".$row["amount"]."</td></tr>";
}
```

Also just noticed that you may also need the `<table>` tags around the content inside the `<div>`

Answer (score 2):

You can also try something like this for better legibility of the code

```
<?php while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["select_bank"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["entry_type"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["income_cat"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["expense_cat"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["expense_cat_sub"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["amount"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }; ?>
```